# Trouble with getting user input using readline native in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, readline

So my issue is that whenever write in a question using

```
   if(Answer !== '123') return rl.write(`Your access has been denied sorry for the inconvience!`)
   });
```

The console doesn't wait for my input. When I run the file It returns `Your access has been denied sorry for the inconvience!` before I even type. Im not sure what I'm doing wrong as it was working earlier. This is my entire file code

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

module.exports.run = async () => {

    rl.question("Password Required: ", function(Answer) {
    if(Answer !== '123') return rl.write(`Your access has been denied sorry for the inconvience!`)
    });

    
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "test",
    description: "Is a copy command "
}
```

and I'm calling the entire module with `return require('./util/test').run();` any help is appreciated!